# What type of regression analysis to use

Tags: r, regression

I would like to study the associations between x (independent variable) and y(dependent variable) controlling for some factors like demographic factor. Both independent and dependent variables have data for 2013 and 2019; however impact of x can be seen on y in several years (some lag time). Which type of regression analysis can be used? Also, for the controlling factors, should I go with 2013 or 2019 data?

Comment: Hi @Lola. It looks like you would maybe benefit from something like a 'distributed lag' model within the context of time series data. This allows you to place a lag independent variable on the right hand side. If you wished to also place the lags of your dependent variable on the right hand side, then you should use an 'autoregressive distributed lag' model.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @EB3112! I will explore the methods you mentioned